# How to send data-id to action?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this function:

Code **PHP:**

```
<?php
foreach($this->pacientsInfo AS $pacient)    
                { ?>

    <button class="inmail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inMail" data-patient-id="<?php echo $pacient['id']; ?>"><i class="fa fa-inbox"></i><span>In-mail</span></button>

<?php

?>
```

This code has the following result:

```
<button class="inmail" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inMail" data-patient-id="191">
```

In-mail

What I want to do is send ID on this form:

Code **HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
    <div id="inbox_message">
        <form method="post" action="<?php  echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()).'/user/sendmessagetoinbox/'; //here I should to add data-patient-id ?>">
            <fieldset>
                <label>Subject</label>
                <input type="text" name="inbox_subject" />
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <label>Message</label>
                <textarea name="inbox_message"></textarea>
            </fieldset>

            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-save send-btn">Send message to inbox</button>
                <!-- <input type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" value="Send message to inbox" /> -->
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

After function `sendmessagetoinbox` I must transmit `data-patient-id`

It takes a function in jquery to do that? You show me a brief example please?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could always just set the submit button value / a hidden value to the `patient-id` on the modal being opened through jquery.

Comment: what is it? bootstap modal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is bootstrap modal popup then you can add an hidden input in your form:

```
   <input type="hidden" value="" name="patient-id" />
</form>
```

Then in the jQuery code you can make use of `show.bs.modal` event and by the `event` object you can find the target element which is clicked and there you can get the `data-patient-id` and just set it in the hidden input:

```
$('#inMail').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var pId = $(event.relatedTarget).data('patientId'); //camelCase, you have - separated data attr
  $(this).find('input[type="hidden"]').val(pId);
});
```

#### [Example @ bootstrap docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target)

Comment: And here I shoul to modify something?  <form method="post" action="<?php  echo $this->serverUrl().str_replace('public','',$this->basePath()).'/user/sendmessagetoinbox/'; //here I should to add data-patient-id ?>">

Comment: @Marius No! you don't have to change anything if you post your form the hidden input value would be passed as `patient-id=FOO`.

Comment: At this code I receive a error "undefined" var pId = $(event.target).data('patientId')
  alert(pId);

Comment: @Marius change `event.target` to `event.relatedTarget`.

Answer (score 3):

no requirement of doing that simply use `<input type="hidden" value="your_id" name="patient-id" />`

Comment: And this input where I add? In form?

Comment: and what values are completed in value=" "?

Comment: which you want to send to other page like `<?php echo $pacient['id']; ?>`

Comment: this answer assumes that the modal form is placed in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$('.inMail').on('click', function (e) {
  var id = $(this).attr('data-target'),
     val = $(this).attr('data-patient-id');
  $('input[name="patient_id"]').remove();
  $(id).find('#inbox_message form').append('<input name="patient_id" type="hidden" value='+val+'>')
})
```

Comment: No need of js, what needed is a hidden input.

Comment: @Jai There are multiple buttons to open the modals, JS is needed to assign the ID to the modal.

Comment: @Madalinivascu You need to assign a name to the hidden input and only add it once. If the modal is closed and opened with a different ID, there will be multiple inputs. Just add a hidden field to the modal code and modify it with `.val()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, this will helpful for you to pass variable to modal popup

```
jsfiddle.net/Au9tc/605
```